# If there exists an element $x$ of order $n$ in $G'$, then we must have an element of order $n$ in $G$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-homomorphism

If there exists a homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$, if there exists an element $x$ of order $n$ in $G'$, then we must have an element of order $n$ in $G$

What if the homomorphism is onto?

Counter example of the first statement : Take the trivial homomorphism from $Z_2 $ to $Z_8$

I'll try to prove the onto case :

Let $x\in G', \; |x|=n \Rightarrow \exists y\in G \; \text{s.t} \; \phi(y)=x \Rightarrow |x| \; \text{divides} \; |y| \Rightarrow |y|=nk \;  \text{f.s} \; k \in N \Rightarrow |y^{k}| = n   $  and so $y^k$ is required element of $G$

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you saying statement of first paragraph is true, or asking if it is? And by second question are you just asking about that statement under the assumption the homomorphism is onto?

Comment: This question is ill-posed at present. Are you hoping the community will help you prove the first sentence? Please make it clear, and demonstrate how you have attempted to solve the problem - this is not a forum where we do your homework for you.

Comment: @coffeemath can you see the edited post please

Comment: @bounceback please see the edited post now

Comment: Well you've butchered the implies symbol, and I don't like your 'f.s', but the argument appears sound. You should be fine.